# show all WordPress categories in a page

Tags: categories

I want to show all WordPress categories in a page.
I use this code:

```
<?php
 $categories = get_categories( array(
 'orderby' => 'name',
 'order'   => 'ASC',
 'exclude' => '1,116',

    ) );
  foreach  ($categories as $category) {
      echo '<div class="item_product">';
      // display category image
              echo '<div class="image_wrapper is-image">';
                  echo do_shortcode(sprintf('[wp_custom_image_category term_id="%s"]',$category->term_id));
            echo '</div>';
            // display category name 
              echo '<div class="desc_left">';
                    echo '<h2 class="podcast_h2"><a href=" ' .get_permalink($category->ID). ' "> '.$category->name.' </a></h2>';
              echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';

} ?>
```

But each category is linked to the same page as the category list
(example.com/list-category)
I want each category link to that category

Answer (score 2):

To get link to category use the function `get_category_link` ([doc here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link)).
Function `get_permalink` is intended for **posts**.

```
echo '<h2 class="podcast_h2"><a href=" ' .get_category_link($category->term_id). ' "> '.$category->name.' </a></h2>'
```

Comment: I used this, but there was the same problem again - 

i used :   get_category_link( $category->term_id ) And my problem is over

Comment: You're right, the `WP_Term` object has a property `term_id` instead `ID`.